# Handling Large HTTP Responses in Angular 8

Tags: json, database, frontend, angular8

Here's a problem to discuss ( I am a beginner )
i am strong in my db images and other data, once i make a GET request to my db it should return a very large json object for example:

```
{
   productName:"X",
   productPrice:200,
   productDescription:"X X XX X X X X X X X X X X X X"
   productImages:"["VERY LARGE STRING in base64 format","VERY LARGE STRING in base64 format","VERY LARGE STRING in base64 format"]"
}
```

it is returned but in a very long time maybe 30Second, my problem is how to stop Component from loading until i get the response????

Comment: It could help some kind of half way solution as ngx-progressbar you can find at github / npm.